# find solution $xdy+2ydx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> solve $xdy+2ydx=0$ using separation of variables and find the constant by $y(x=2)=1$

$$xdy+2ydx=0\Rightarrow -\frac{dy}{2y}=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Integrate 2 sides: $$-\frac{1}{2}ln|2y|=ln|x|$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{|2y}}=x\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{2x^2}+c$$

$$1=\frac{1}{8}+c\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{7}{8}$$

When do I need to add the contrast in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$-\frac12 \log(|y|)=\log(|x|)+C\implies |y|^{-1/2}=A|x|\implies |y|=\frac{A'}{x^2}$$

so that

$$y=\pm A'x^{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think your second line should read:

$$ -\frac{1}{2}\ln |y| = \ln |x| + c$$

and yes this is where you add the arbitrary constant term